# Recursing through a AST using DFS

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to recurse through an annotated syntax tree.

My aim is to increment a counter once it sees a particular type of node.

```
Void *DFS(State *N, IrNode *node, int Counter)
{    
    Counter=0

    if (node->irLeftChild == NULL && 
        node->irRightChild == NULL && 
        node->isVisited == false && 
        node->type == kNewtonIrNodeType_Tidentifier)
    {
        Counter+=1
        node->isVisited = true;
        return ;
    }

    DFS(N, node->irLeftChild);

    DFS(N, node->irRightChild); 
}
```

Is there a better way to recurse through the tree?

Comment: That's because you don't keep/return the results of the two recursive calls.

Comment: Are you sure you even want to return anything? - what should be the result of a node with two children?

Comment: If your goal is to increment all leaf nodes of a particular type there really should not be a return value. If you do want to only do this once and return one node then your calls to DFS need to return a node or null

Comment: Ok so how would I integrate the counter in this case? 

I have modified the code above. Is this a good way?

Comment: Apologies for the errors, I have now edited the code

Comment: @TriposG: Might want to try editing the code again - you're not returning a `void *` pointer, and any good compiler will ignore everything involving `Counter` because the value in the variable is never used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do; but if you're trying to return a total count of entries that matched the criteria to the caller you probably want something like:

```
int DFS(State *N, IrNode *node) {    
    int Counter = 0;

    if (node->irLeftChild == NULL &&  node->irRightChild == NULL &&  node->isVisited == false && node->type == kNewtonIrNodeType_Tidentifier) {
        Counter += 1;
        node->isVisited = true;
    }
    Counter += DFS(N, node->irLeftChild);
    Counter += DFS(N, node->irRightChild); 
    return Counter;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I am getting an infinite recursion error. 

error: all paths through this function will call itself [-Werror,-Winfinite-recursion]

Comment: I am trying to recurse through a AST which doesnt have a particular structure. However, I know that all the nodes that I want to count have no child and are of the type kNewtonIrNodeType_Tidentifier but to avoid visiting the same node again I added a isVisited Struct in the IrNode

Comment: Ah - you'll need to make sure a node exists before recursing into it; like `if(node->irLeftChild != NULL)  { Counter += DFS(N, node->irLeftChild); }`.